# How to split a column using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file as follows

```
1RB9A
2B97A
2O9SA
1GWEA
3Q8JA
2YKZA
3O4PA
```

I would like to get the output as shown below.

```
    1RB9 A
    2B97 A
    2O9S A
    1GWE A
    3Q8J A
    2YKZ A
    3O4P A
```

How can I do this with awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '{sub(/.$/, " &")} 1' file
3A38 A
2VB1 J
1US0 A
3R6J C
```

#### Using sed

```
$ sed 's/.$/ &/' file1
3A38 A
2VB1 J
1US0 A
3R6J C
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My file has 16000 lines. This code doesn't work with my file. But the code is working with the sample.

Comment: @andrew From the large problem file, pick say 2 or 3 lines that __do not__ work and show them.  By the way, do the problematic lines have trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code:

```
awk -F, '{$(NF)=" " $(NF);}1' OFS=, file.csv

a,a,a,1,2, 3
g,g,g,j,s, a
1,1,2,2,5, 6
```

and find out many awk and sed commands in this website. It clearly explains the commands and It's very helpful.
 http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/11/awk-examples-insert-remove-update-fields.html